# Foregin key constraint on pivot table in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, foreign-keys

I have rather simple and silly question regarding foreign keys and laravel's schema builder(or rather a misunderstanding on how foreign keys should work perhaps).

I have the following 3 tables:

Blueprint

1. id
2. name
3. some other fields

Collection

1. id
2. description
3. some other fields

BlueprintCollection

1. id
2. blueprint_id
3. collection_id

I want to create a foreign key that links the Blueprint's `id` to BlueprintCollection's `blueprint_id` and do the same for Collection.

It's my understanding that I should do the following

```
$table->foreign('blueprint_id')->references('id')->on('blueprint_table');
```

With `->onDelete('cascade` or `->onUpdate('cascade');` I don't have to do this part, however I want it to be this way.

This should be done in the BlueprintCollection table.

However, if I'm understanding this correctly it will delete the entry in the Blueprint table if the row that contains the `blueprint_id` that references `id` on Blueprint will be deleted.

Obviously, since it's a junction table I don't want to do that, rather the other way around. If an entry in Blueprint is deleted, I want to delete the entry in the BlueprintCollection table.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next:

```
$table
    ->foreign('blueprint_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('blueprint_table')
    ->onDelete('cascade')
    ->onUpdate('cascade');
```